# Varying Marker color based on the data value in SGPlot - SeriesPlot

Tags: graph, sas

Is there any way to vary colors of a marker in a SGPlot-seriesplot ?. By vary i mean, the color of the marker should be be *red*, *yellow* or *green* depending on the value of a variable in the dataset varying from *low*, *moderate* to *high*. Also note that I need a single line connecting all the markers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do that using SGPLOT exclusively, but if you add an annotate dataset, it should be trivial to replace the SGPLOT markers (which you could then skip entirely) with your own annotated markers of whatever color you want.  If it's a single panel SGPLOT, you can use the `datavalue` drawspace to place the x/y coordinates directly from your dataset and then you adjust the color however you want (as you have a dataset with one row per marker).

See the following for more information:
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/277-2011.pdf